# How to find WooCommerce variation by attributes?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I'm working on adding custom functionality on top of Woocommerce, and I need to find the variation id for a variable product based on the attributes I've selected.

For example, if I have a burrito with a meat attribute being 'Chicken', 'Steak', and 'Pork', then there are three variations. How would I find the variation with the attribute being chicken?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to find variations in js, then you can find it them in form tag. Get the whole array of variations along with attributes and variation ID. You can use this attribute's data "data-product_variations".
2. If you want to get variation attributes in PHP, you can use this code:
   $product->get_variation_attributes();
   From this array, you can easily identify variations along with attributes.